# Hindu Texts Kali Wearing Sari ? Idols Question

Tags: shiva, durga, kali, idols

Just wondering about this, in many Kali Puja, Shyama Puja ceremonies they have Kali murti atop MahaDev as per usual. But she is sometimes wearing full on rich brocade sari with almost bridal level stuffs going on.

These don’t match the descriptions I’ve read but I’ve read much less than you guys here as my Sanskrit/Hindi skills are not great, so I’ve got limited info from English translations excerpts.

In Tantra texts or Hinduism texts, is Kali ever described as being in silk saris huge bridal stuffs ?

Feels like it goes against all the Hindu symbolism of her that I’ve read (and loved so much !)

This kind of bridal finery looks great on the Durga murti/pandals, and I’ve read descriptions of Durga like this, but seems weird to me with Kali. I love both of them as depictions of AdiShakti but I always prefer the murtis where Kali isn’t done up like bridal mannequin in wedding display.

It’s like putting Shiv in the kind of clothes Krishn/Vishnu wears, doesn’t look right at all. He only dressed that way when he married Parvati, I think ? Rest of the time he looks magnificent and awesome in his Vasuki, trident, ashes, Ganga on head etc

Just wondering if Hinduism texts have references for this type of Kali murti anywhere. Any info greatly appreciated, thx :)

Edit : Might be an idiotic question. (I’ve posted many of those haha) Is it perhaps just artistic license, artistic liberties taken by the person making the idol ? There are many different types and styles of Kali and Durga idols.

Edit : Ok from Rickross’s comment, appears to just be artistic license taken by the people setting up the pandals, nothing to do with actual descriptions of Kali Maa in Hinduism texts, Tantra texts, etc

Comment: She is always depicted as Digambari (who wears the directions as clothes or in other words she will appear as not wearing clothes to others). Never wears outfits like sarees etc. Same is the case with Goddess Tara, who is the second Mahavidya.

Comment: @Rickross Thx ! And that’s what I thought, no wonder the sari draped bridal mannequin type idols of her look so weird to me. Just doesn’t fit the descriptions I’ve read of Kali in any way. Ok, so must be artistic liberties taken by the people setting up the puja pandals. The murtis where she’s not covered with finery look a million times more cool.